# How can I build this CSS without using multiple P tags?

Tags: css

I want my finished product to look like this:

```
   My

Shopping

  Cart
```

Which, I've gotten it to work so far but I'm using three paragraph tags

```
<div><p>My</p><p>Shopping</p><p>Cart</p></div>
```

- Outer most div has `width:200px`
- P tags are `width:100%` and `text-align:center`
- [JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MGXkA/)

Is there any way to accomplish this without all the p tags? I don't need to get rid of them but I like to think there is a better way.

Comment: You can use block elements other than p tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the [`word spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) to the width of the container.

```
div {
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    word-spacing: 200px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/MGXkA/1/)

- P.S - Actually you can also set it to a very large value (`32767px` on `Chrome 29.0.1` and infinite values on `FF23`) and it'll work the same way. That way it won't be coupled with the container's width.

Comment: I tried `word-spacing:9999em` and found out it breaks in chrome (mac) after `2047em`. Which apparently, the magic number changes per environment (it's 3k+ on my test page). Pretty nuts right? +1 for an otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Works on my Chrome (windows) until `32767px` (`2^15 - 1` or simply  `Int16.MaxValue`). This is an extremely large number and I honestly don't think you'll ever reach there.

Comment: I went with `999em` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one `<p>` tag for all the text and then force line breaks with `<br>` tags like so:

**HTML**

```
<p>My<br/><br/>
Shopping<br/><br/>
Cart</p>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGXkA/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use br tag and css property of line-height to achieve desired effect

```
<style>
  .centerIt{
    line-height:1.3;/**choose as per your requirement**/
    text-align:center;       
    width:200px;
   }
</style>
<div class='centerIt'>My<br />Shopping<br />Cart</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkYrk/